# How to increase quality of chest x-ray image

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network

For now, I have a project about identifying and predicting lung nodule on x-ray images. However, I'm not expert in a field of image processing, so I do not know how to increase the quality of the image before pushing it into the CNN model. An example of image is png file... [This is an CXR image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwF2U.png)

If you have any techniques to improve quality of image, Could you recommend it? I need some helps ~

Comment: You can try [CLAHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization). It [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fep9c.png) nice, but I have no idia if it helps before pushing it into the CNN model.

Comment: Do you know what is difference between adaptive histogram equalisation and histogram equalisation?

Comment: Histogram equalization output is a flat histogram. Adaptive HistEQ limits the contrast of the output (more gaussian like). The local EQ divides the image to small blocks, and applies EQ to each block